# How to add an ActiveX control to a Visual Studio 2008 VisualC++ Win32 project

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, activex

I downloaded the Mint Workbench v5 from ABB Motions website.  Downloading the Mint Workbench put ActiveX control files onto my PC so I can use them to interface with a controller that will control a motor.  Using a VisualC++ Win32 project in Visual Studio I created a bunch of functions.  One is called Test1().  Test1() will need to use a few of ABB Motions ActiveX control functions to set and get the speed of the motor several times then do something with the data.  I would like to wrap all of this into a dll I can use with National Instruments Test Stand.  Test stand will then use my dll to call the Test1() function and do some other stuff.  I have everything working besides I can't figure out how to add ABBs ActiveX controls to my Visual C++ Win32 project.

Comment: Did you find problems following [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yc13as7d(v=vs.90).aspx) or [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asach87d(v=vs.90).aspx)? If so, perhaps you can be specific about where you get problems.

Comment: Added more information. Instead of trying to create an ActiveX control I want to use an existing ActiveX control.